# Material-UI how to set a zIndex for a div?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, z-index, material-ui

I'm new to Material-UI. I understand that there are 6 possible zIndices. The documentation states that

> zIndex can be used to change the level of each component.

How do I change the zIndex of a custom div that I created?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I realized that you need to use a Paper element instead of a div. You can find the documentation for the component here:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/paper

Answer (score 0):

You seem zoned out a little. zDepth and zIndex are completely different. zIndex is used for aligning the views on top of each other, as in which view should be on top of the other.

zDepth on the other hand in the material ui paper component is only used to assign the depth of 'shadow' of the paper.

Hope that resolves it.